# Why does the script ignore the part after the first WaitForSeconds()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I am trying to use `WaitForSeconds()` in my game to perform a scene.
I would love to here improvements and answers to the not working `WaitForSeconds()` (Its just ignores the part after I start to use `WaitForSeconds()`)
The script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class FoodManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool[] isFull;
    public GameObject[] slots;

    public GameObject[] itemNames;
    public GameObject[] itemImages;
    public GameObject[] itemAmounts;
    public GameObject foodObject;
    public GameObject mainPanel;

    public string[] foodNames;
    public Sprite[] foodImages;
    public Sprite[] foodHalfImages;

    public GameObject foodPanel;

    public GameObject bird;

    private int _lastFood;
    private int _hunger;

    void Update()
    {
        _hunger = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("_hunger");
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (isFull[i] == true)
                slots[i].SetActive(true);
            if (isFull[i] == false)
                slots[i].SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void addItem(int max, string itemName, GameObject itemImage, int addingAmount)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
        {
            if (isFull[j] == true && itemNames[j].GetComponent<Text>().text == itemName)
            {
                itemAmounts[j].GetComponent<Text>().text = (int.Parse(itemAmounts[j].GetComponent<Text>().text) + addingAmount).ToString();
                _lastFood = j;
                return;
            }
            if (isFull[j] == false)
            {
                isFull[j] = true;
                itemNames[j].GetComponent<Text>().text = itemName;
                itemAmounts[j].GetComponent<Text>().text = addingAmount.ToString();
                itemImages[j].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = foodImages[j];
                _lastFood = j;
                return;
            }
            if (isFull[j] == true && int.Parse(itemAmounts[j].GetComponent<Text>().text) == 0)
            {
                isFull[j] = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void foodButtonsBehavior(int a)
    {
        if(a >= 0 && a <= 5)
        {
            StartCoroutine(foodEat(slots[a]));
        }
        if (a == 7) //add food button
        {
            addItem(7, "Special Seeds", itemImages[1], 2);
        }
    }
    public void closeFoodMenu()
    {
        foodPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    public IEnumerator foodEat(GameObject slot)
    {
        mainPanel.SetActive(false);
        foodPanel.SetActive(false); // Start Of Animation
        itemAmounts[_lastFood].GetComponent<Text>().text = (int.Parse(itemAmounts[_lastFood].GetComponent<Text>().text) - 1).ToString();
        moveFood(-1f, -1f); // Resetting Position for the food
        foodObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = foodImages[_lastFood];
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.1f);
        print("Continuing");
        foodObject.SetActive(true);
        //bird.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        bird.transform.position = new Vector2(0, -2.4f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f);
        moveFood(-1f, -2f);
        bird.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        bird.transform.position = new Vector2(0, -2.4f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f);
        moveFood(-1f, -2.7f);
        bird.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        bird.transform.position = new Vector2(0, -2.4f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        foodObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = foodHalfImages[_lastFood];
        bird.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        bird.transform.position = new Vector2(0, -2.4f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        foodObject.SetActive(false);
        bird.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        bird.transform.position = new Vector2(0, -2.4f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8f);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_hunger", _hunger + 24);
        foodPanel.SetActive(true); // End Of Animation
        mainPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
    private void moveFood(float x, float y)
    {
        foodObject.transform.position = new Vector2(x, y);
    }
    public void changeBird(GameObject x)
    {
        bird = x;
    }
}
```

I would love to get some help here, as this is critical for my game and I couldn't find my answer online, so I would appreciate if someone decides to help with the problem. (Srry stackOverFlow wouldn't let me post without the last lines.)

Comment: So you're saying that it never prints `continuing`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All the actions before the first ```WaitForSeconds()``` worked, I checked.

Comment: Is this script attached to the food panel, or a child of the food panel?

Comment: It's a child of the food panel, and I made an Empty Object called FoodManager and hooked the script to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something important to note is that Coroutines only run when the the gameobject it is attached to remains active. From the [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) documentation:

> A coroutines also stops when the GameObject
>    it is attached to is disabled with SetActive(false)

This behaviour is consistent with the error you are seeing, albeit a little confusing because the code appears to continue running after you disable the object. There's a very nuanced explanation, but for a simplified version: SetActive(false) waits until the end of the frame to stop MonoBehaviours running on the gameobject.

Comment: Wait, so I do I solve this? There aren't any ```SetActive(false)``` right before the ```yield return new WaitForSeconds()```

Comment: How do I make the ```foodPanel``` disappear without stopping the ```WaitForSeconds()```?

Comment: @Quartz you will need to move the coroutine logic to a game object that is not being disabled.